# Null Pointer Exception on Buffer IO

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception, socket.io, buffer

For my Software Engineering class my group has to get a camera stream from a server and send it to a client via a socket.  We do this by constantly sending images through a socket.  When we try to run our program we only get one image but the next image turns up as null and therefore we get a nullpointer exception.

Here is the UserClient class.  The UserClient receives a sequence of images.  The null pointer comes up in the run method, I labeled it with a comment.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package communication;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import userpc.RoverGUI;

/**
 * A simple Swing-based client for the capitalization server. It has a main
 * frame window with a text field for entering strings and a textarea to see the
 * results of capitalizing them.
 */
public class UserClient extends Thread{

    //ObjectInputStream input;
    Socket s = null;
    boolean done = false;
    String serverAddress;
    RoverGUI gui;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n"
                + "running the date service on port 9090:");
        try {
            UserClient c = new UserClient(null, serverAddress);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public UserClient(RoverGUI gui, String serverAddress) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        this.gui=gui;
        this.serverAddress=serverAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (!done) {
            try {
                if (serverAddress.equals("")) {
                    throw new UnknownHostException();
                }
                s = new Socket(serverAddress, 9090);
                //input =new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                done = true;
            } catch (ConnectException e) {
                gui.display("Wait for servor...");
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                gui.display("Un known Host Exception Occur...");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UserClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        while(true){
            try {
                    gui.setIcons(ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(s.getInputStream())),null);
//NULL POINTER HERE
                //System.out.println(input.readLine());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UserClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        //input.close();
        s.close();
    }
}
```

The RoverServer sends the stream of images.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package communication;

import camera.ImageBuffer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author junxin
 */
public class RoverServer implements Runnable {

    Socket socket = null;
    ServerSocket listener = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ImageBuffer ib;
    RoverClient client;

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        try {
            ImageBuffer ib=new ImageBuffer();
            RoverServer server=new RoverServer(ib);
            new Thread(server).start();
            RoverClient client= new RoverClient("150.250.220.214");
            client.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RoverServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public RoverServer(ImageBuffer ib) {
        this.ib=ib;
        try {
            listener = new ServerSocket(9090);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RoverServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = listener.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accept");

            out =new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while(true){
                //out.printf("", ib.getImage(),ib.getImage2());
                out.writeObject(ib.getImage());
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to accept client!");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RoverServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: how does `ib.getImage()` work? btw, you need to implement a way to wait for an image from server. your server is sleeping for 100ms, but your client is constantly trying to read the input stream... which is null when there is no data being sent...

Comment: Do you see any string like "Wait for servor...", "Un known Host Exception Occur..." on gui or `Logger.getLogger(UserClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);` in logger?

Comment: I do not think inputs stream is null when server sends no data. I do not have eclipse/jdk at hand but I Think in that case the input streams blocks and gets 0 for available.

Comment: NullPointerExceptin comes when you un-comment those commented-out lines?

Comment: If gui.setIcons(ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(s.getInputStream())),null); is the source of the NPE it would be helpfull to know exactly which part evaluates to null, perhaps the createImageInputStream?

Comment: You must post the stack trace and an indication of which line in your code threw it.

Comment: we implemented an if statement in the client to only display the image when it is not null and to print when the image received is/is not null. The first image has data. Every one after that is null. For some reason only one image is sent then it's all null.

Comment: I think the first parameter is the one that returned null.

Answer (score 0):

```
 gui.setIcons(ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(s.getInputStream())),null);
```

assigns the sockets input stream to a new reader, right? 
 
That is allowed only once per stream.
Also if you assign the stream to multiple reader, only the first reader can read from the stream
In the folling example, only first reader gets values (Server sends hi\nat\nall):

```
        BufferedReader firstReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader secondReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("str = " + firstReader.readLine()); //str = hi
        System.out.println("str = " + secondReader.readLine()); //str = null !!!!!
        System.out.println("str = " + firstReader.readLine()); //str = at
        System.out.println("str = " + firstReader.readLine()); //str = all
```

You shoud create one reader per connection and re-use it in your loop.